# How to implement PDF file upload feature using django rest framework and MySQL?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend

I'm making Website using Next.Js(v13.1.6) as frontend and Django REST Framework(v3.14.0, django:v4.1.6) as backend, AWS RDS MySQL as Database.

I want to make user upload and download pdf in client. How to implement this feature in **backend**?

I heard that when saving static file(like image file) in django, usally use S3 as storage to be efficient. Is it the same when saving a **pdf** file?

I want to know is it okay saving pdf file just in mysql without s3.

I want to make user upload and download pdf in client. How to implement this feature in **backend**? I want to know is it okay saving pdf file just in mysql without s3 in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi yes you will need a third party bucket/storage provider to efficiently handle your or your app users uploaded(media) files.

If you have not done it yet.. try the following link,
it uses cloudinary for serving media files, however you can use google, amazon or any provider that provides storages.

https://www.section.io/engineering-education/uploading-images-to-cloudinary-from-django-application/

Note: you should use your database to store the destination of your files, not the File itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).